# ajax response inside a function by ob clean

Tags: php, function, arguments

I'm looking for a way to calling a function by a function and get it's content executed in the function like:

```
function response($execute){
    ob_clean();
    $execute();
    die();
}
```

so when i call, i want to give it a process as argument, like:

```
response(echo("hi"));
```

Comment: are you expecting `hi` function should be called ?

Comment: @SahilGulati i want to get echo function as parameter

Comment: Do you want only echo function as parameters or any `anonymous` function or closures?

Comment: echo function is an example, i want to get anonymous functions too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP using anonymous function.**

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/761773)

```
function response($execute)
{
    if(is_callable($execute))
    {
        $execute("some-value");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not a function";
    }
}

response(function($someVariable){
    echo "Hi i am in anonymous function with 1st argument ".$someVariable;
});
response("Hi");
```

Comment: Thank you master!

Comment: is there anyway to detect that $execute is function or variable inside of response() ?